# Empty variables passed via PHP

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm receiving some data via a URL from s2member - it looks something like this.

`https://www.myurl.net/?s2_payment_notification=yes&user_id=106&first_name=John&last_name=Smith&payer_email=john@smith.com&address_one=AddressLine1&address_two=AddressLine2&address_three=AddressLine3&postcode=postcode&cv1=11318&coupon_code=`

I'm using this with WooCommerce to programatically create an order using wc_create_order. I've managed to get woocommerce to recognise and apply the coupon if it's present in the URL and create the order. It works beautifully when theres a coupon code present in the URL. However when it's not present (like the URL above) the script doesn't complete, leaving me with no order created.

```
 $order = wc_create_order();
$order->add_product(get_product($tier), 1);
$order->set_address($address, 'billing');
$order->set_address($address, 'shipping');
if ($coupon_code == '35off1' || $coupon_code == '35off2' || $coupon_code == '35off3') 
        {   
        $order->add_coupon($coupon_code, 6.65);
        $order->set_total(6.65, 'order_discount'); 
        }
$order->calculate_totals(); 
$order->payment_complete();
```

What happens when the variable is empty?

I've also tried this to no avail:

```
$order = wc_create_order();
$order->add_product(get_product($tier), 1);
$order->set_address($address, 'billing');
$order->set_address($address, 'shipping');
if ($coupon_code == '35off1' || $coupon_code == '35off2' || $coupon_code == '35off3') 
        {   
        $order->add_coupon($coupon_code, 6.65);
        $order->set_total(6.65, 'order_discount');
        $order->calculate_totals(); 
        $order->payment_complete();
        }
else if (empty($coupon_code)) 
$order->calculate_totals(); 
$order->payment_complete();
```

Comment: It should work... No specific warning or error in logs ?

Comment: Nope, just a buddypress error that seems quite common `[31-Dec-2014 13:36:40 UTC] PHP Notice:  bp_setup_current_user was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. The current user is being initialized without using $wp->init(). Please see <a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 1.7.)`

Comment: The woocommerce logs haven't been updated since the 20/12/2014 2:50 pm) but they're blank anyway? I've got WP logging enabled Do i need to do anything more to ensure Woocommerce logging is on?

Comment: Did you take a look into the php logs on the server ?

Comment: Yes, there's only a buddypress error I listed above